# The nav disappear when I visit the website with a tablet (landscape mode)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I created a menu for a responsive website.

When the site is viewed in a normal browser whose width is less than 768px, the navigation menu items are stacked and hidden. The user needs to click the toggle a tag to reveal the navigation items. When the browser width is more than 992px, the navigation menu items are displayed in a line.

My problem happens when I open the website on a iPad. If the user first open the site on a iPad in portrait mode (width = 768px) and clicks toggle a tag to reveal the navigation menu and then clicks the toggle a tag again to hide the navigation menu. Now if the user rotates his iPad to landscape mode (width > 768px), the navigation menu disappears.

But if the user opens the site on a iPad in portrait mode and then rotates it to landscape mode without clicking the toggle a tag, the navigation menu is available in landscape mode.

I'm working with basic jQuery.
I think it happens because with "fadeToggle" I play with display none and display block and when I rotate the tablet, it doesn't recognize that the resolution changed.

How could I resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

```js
//Open and close Nav
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".open-nav").click(function() {
    $(".main-nav").fadeToggle(500);
    $(".open-nav").css("display", "none");
    $(".close-nav").css("display", "block");
  });
  $(".close-nav").click(function() {
    $(".main-nav").fadeToggle(500);
    $(".close-nav").css("display", "none");
    $(".open-nav").css("display", "block");
  });
});
```

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #FFF;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.open-nav {
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.close-nav {
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-nav {
  float: right;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.main-nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.main-nav ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.main-nav ul li a {
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-nav ul li .btn-primary {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.main-nav ul li a.btn-primary:hover {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.main-nav ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: solid #ff0054 2px;
}

.active {
  border-bottom: solid #ff0054 2px;
}


/* Medium devices (tablets, 768px and 992px)*/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
  a.open-nav {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  a.close-nav {
    display: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .main-nav {
    display: none;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #fff;
    float: none;
    z-index: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    margin-left: -50vw;
    margin-right: -50vw;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .main-nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 25%;
  }
  .main-nav ul li {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .main-nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 26px;
    margin: 0 30px 60px 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <a class="open-nav col-xs-3 hidden-md" title="Menu">Click to Open</a>
    <a class="close-nav col-xs-3 hidden-md" title="Menu">Click to Close</a>
    <nav class="main-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="active" title="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Link 1">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Link 2">Link 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: remove `.main-nav` display none property from media

Comment: If I remove "display none" from the CSS, the nav will be open when I visit the page.I don't want that this happen.

Comment: use visibility hidden for that

Comment: I'm sorry @NishargShah but it doesn't work. :(
Thank you anyway for your help.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: Hi @j08691, thanks for your answer.

Yes, I'm using Bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. Just in case anyone else has the same problem.

I solved my issue adding another media query on my CSS code:

```
/* Large devices and landscape tablets (tablets or desktops, 993px and 1366px)*/
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) and (min-width: 993px) and (max-width: 1366px) {

    .main-nav {
        display: block!important;
    }

}
```

Thanks anyway for your help.